# Data is changed in realm database with delay

Tags: android, database, realm

I'm writing some data to realm database on Android:

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            realm.executeTransaction({
                val ValueModel = 
    realm.where(ValueModel::class.java).findFirst() ?: CnamModel()
                valueModel.value = value
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(valueModel)
            })
```

A few seconds later I'm trying to read it:

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
                val valueModel = 
   realm.where(ValueModel::class.java).findFirst()
   val myValue = valueModel.value
```

The problem is that when I do it soon after write, the db has old value.  It takes more than 10 seconds before I can get data from realm an get newly written value. How can I solve the problems, to be able to read new value just after end of write transaction?

Comment: Probably that you are using `val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()` instead of `Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->`.

Comment: But I don't know what thread you're running this on, so code context would help.

Comment: I'm using it with Rx java, the actions are being invoked with scheduler: Schedulers.io()

Comment: Thank you EpicPandaForce, I will check tomorrow if .use() resolves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you're closing the realm or not but try below code and let me know if it works.

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
// do something
}
```

> in Java

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
// do something
}
```

Use `realm.insertOrUpdate(...)` if you're not dealing with returned result of `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(..)`.